# onbeforeunload function empty fields

Tags: javascript

I have a function `save` that needs to be called on the onbeforeunload  event. This is my code:

```
var data = new Array();
window.onbeforeunload = save;

function save(){
     console.log(data);
}

function update(){
    data.push('test');
}
setInterval(update, 100);
```

The data array is empty when the save method gets called. But in the field are actually lots of 'test' elements. So why is it empty?

Comment: Is it actually logging an empty array, or just not logging anything at all?

Comment: it is logging an empty array

Comment: Works ok [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4akdx/) in Chrome (added message so console won't go away).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return something to test anything.

```
function save(){
     console.log(data);
      return "Testing console output";
}
```

This is working fine for me.